# Using gnosis safe with ledger hardware wallet

Tags: multisignature, ledger-nano-s, gnosis

I have created a 2/2 multisig wallet using the Gnosis Safe with one of the signer being a ledger hardware wallet.

I have done 2 tests:

1. The ledger is the first to cosign, then the ledger screen will display a rather cryptic transaction hash and ask for validation
2. The ledger is the last to sign, then it will ask me to validate the amount (incorrectly displayed, I wanted to transfer 0.2ETH and it was displaying 0) and the destination address (again, showing incorrect data and not the address I was sending my transaction to)

So either it shows (1) no relevant information regarding the transaction or (2) incorrect data - is this a known limitation using Gnosis Safe?

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: No code, I am using the web interface for the Gnosis Safe on Rinkeby at https://rinkeby.gnosis-safe.io/app/#

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will quote the answer I got from the Gnosis team on their discord:

> For 1 the web app requests to sign a message and ledger displays a
> hash of a hash of that message (this is a ledger ux issue). For 2 you
> are signing a contract interaction that triggers a transfer from your
> safe, therefore ledger will not display it. Ledger would only display
> it if you transfer funds from your ledger account.

> Proper display of contract interactions are a shortcoming of ledger,
> it would require support for eip-712 from ledger to improve this to
> some extend, but this is out of our scope as it requires changes in
> the ledger firmware

> I think most hw currently have similar limitations

Really bad news at it means HW are pretty much useless with Gnosis Safe

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to sign a transaction with ledger:

https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4795041-sign-transactions-with-a-trezor-hardware-wallet

Here's how to confirm transaction with ledger (not pretty, but apparently doable):

https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4818770-how-to-verify-gnosis-safe-transactions-on-a-hardware-wallet

Answer (score -1):

You can use Gnosis Safe through the website with Firefox, MetaMask, Ledger